# Where to put tumblr html code to open permalinks in new tab

Tags: html

I've searched around and figured that I need to add `target="_blank"` but I'm not sure where. I've tried placing it at various places after `<a href="{Permalink}"` but it didn't seem to do anything

I want to have it so that when someone clicks on a post/photo on the main page it'll open the permalink of that post in a new tab.

Here is my complete html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><html><head>
 
<title>{title}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="{RSS}" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1220" />
 
<!-- DEFAULT VARIABLES -->
<meta name="color:Background" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="color:Center" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="color:Text" content="#000000" />
<meta name="color:Link" content="#5c5c5c"/>
<meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#5c5c5c" />
<meta name="color:Sidebar Link Background" content="#cfcfcf" />
<meta name="color:Blog Title" content="#5c5c5c" />
<meta name="color:Scrollbar" content="#7e817e"/>
<meta name="image:Background" content="" />
<meta name="image:Sidebar" content="" />
<meta name="if:2 Columns" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:3 Columns" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Rounded Photos" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Show Blog Title" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Blog Title A" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Blog Title B" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Blog Title C" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Link Style 1" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Link Style 2" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Show Photo Permalinks" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Post Border" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Post Shadow" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Post Shadow on Hover" content="1"/>
<meta name="text:Ask Title" content="Message" />
<meta name="text:Link One" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link One Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Two" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Two Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Three" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Three Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link Four" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Four Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Five" content="" />
<meta name="text:link Five Title" content="" />
<!---   STYLESHEETS & STATIC UPLOADS   --->
<link href="http://static.tumblr.com/ek9ly4s/emomovvhc/animate-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://static.tumblr.com/6jwx45k/0bMmpcsel/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu|Open+Sans|Lekton|Pacifico|Gloria+Hallelujah|Viga' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6jwx45k/qnrmqhe43/ifie1.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6jwx45k/QcKmqhe47/ifie2.js"></script>
 
<style type="text/css">

html{
{block:indexpage}
{block:if3columns}margin-left:245px;{/block:if3columns}
{block:if2columns}margin-left:200px;{/block:if2columns}{/block:indexpage}
{block:permalinkpage}margin-left:100px;{/block:permalinkpage}
cursor:crosshair;
height:103%;}
 
body, p {
font-family:Ubuntu;
font-size:10px;
font-style: normal;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
color:{color:text};}
 
body {
cursor:crosshair;
background-color:{color:background};
background-image:url({image:Background});
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat;}
 
a {
text-decoration:none;
color:{color:text};
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
transition: all 0.4s linear;}
 
a:link, a:active, a:visited{
color: {color:Link};
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;-o-transition: all   0.6s ease-out;transition: all 0.6s ease-out;}
 
a:hover{
color:{color:link hover};}
 
img {{block:ifRoundedPhotos}border-radius:5px;{/block:ifroundedphotos}}
img:hover{opacity:1.0;-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;-o-transition: all   0.6s ease-out;transition: all 0.6s ease-out;cursor:crosshair;}
 
#wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;}
 
.clear {
text-align:left;clear: both;}
 
#entry.masonry-brick {
top: 0 !important;
left: 0 !important;}
 
#infscr-loading {
position: absolute!important;
width: 16px!important;
height: 11px!important;
bottom: 0px!important;
left: 48.5%!important;
margin-top: 10px!important;
margin-bottom: 5px!important;}
 
.supreme{text-align:right;margin-top:10px;}
 
.title{
text-align:center;
font-size:14px;
line-height:16px;}
 
blockquote{
padding:0px 0px 2px 1px;
margin:0px 0px 2px 1px;
border-left: 1px dotted #555555;}
 
.blogtitle{font-size:10px;line-height:40px;text-align:center;letter-spacing:1px;
padding-top:3px;
{block:ifBlogTitleA}font-family:Pacifico;padding-bottom:13px;{/block:ifBlogTitleA}
{block:ifBlogTitleB}font-family:courier new;letter-spacing:3px;
text-transform:uppercase;{/block:ifBlogTitleB}
{block:ifBlogTitleC}font-family:'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;padding-bottom:8px;{/block:ifBlogTitleC}}
.blogtitle a{color:{color:Blog Title};text-transfrom:uppercase;}
 
.description{margin-top:7px;margin-bottom:7px;text-align:center;font-family:courier new;letter-spacing:1px;
text-transform:uppercase;color:#5c5c5c;}
 
#content{
margin:auto;position:relative;
{block:IndexPage}
{block:if3columns}width:930px;{/block:if3columns}
{block:if2columns}width:730px;{/block:if2columns}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}width:500px;{/block:PermalinkPage}}
 
.sidebar{width:200px;background-color:{color:center};
{block:ifpostborder}
border:1px solid #ccc;
{/block:ifpostborder}
padding:0px;
margin-left:-225px;
position:fixed;
z-index:100;
margin-top:35px;
font-size:10px;
font-family:courier;
{block:indexpage}
{block:IfPostShadow}box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px #a3a3a3;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;}{/block:IfPostShadow}
{/block:indexpage}}
 
.text{{block:indexpage}width:248px;{/block:indexpage}
{block:permalinkpage}width:500px;{/block:permalinkpage}}
.photoset{{block:indexpage}width:248px;overflow:hidden;{/block:indexpage}
{block:permalinkpage}width:500px;{/block:permalinkpage}}
.photo{width:300px;height:auto;background-color:{color:center};}
.photo img{width:300px;-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in;{block:ifRoundedPhotos}border-radius:5px;{/block:ifroundedPhotos}}
.photo img:hover{-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in;}
.photobig{width:500px;height:auto;background-color:{color:center};}
.photobig img{width:500px;-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in;{block:ifRoundedPhotos}border-radius:5px;{/block:ifroundedPhotos}}
.photobig img:hover{-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in;}
 
.entry{
margin:5px 0px 0px 5px;
padding:0px 0px 0px px;
background-color:{color:center};
{block:IndexPage}
width:300px;
overflow:hidden;
{block:ifpostborder}
border:1px solid #ccc;
{/block:ifpostborder}
{block:IfPostShadow}
box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px #a3a3a3;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;}
{/block:IfPostShadow}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:500px;
height:auto;
{/block:PermalinkPage}}
 
{block:IfPostShadowonHover}
.entry:hover, .sidebar:hover{
box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px #a3a3a3;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;}
{/block:IfPostShadowonHover}
 
 
/*  SCROLL BAR APPEARANCE  */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
background-color:{color:scrollbar};
height:10px;width:10px;opacity:1;
-webkit-border-radius:0px;border:3px {color:background} solid;}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
background-color:#4c4f50;opacity:1;
height:10px !important;border:3px {color:background} solid;
-webkit-border-radius:0px;}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
height:10px;
width:10px;
background-color:{color:background};
-webkit-border-radius:0px;}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
background-color:{color:background};}
 
::-webkit-resizer {
background-color:{color:background};}
.clearfix:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0}.clearfix{display:inline-block}html[xmlns] .clearfix{display:block}* html .clearfix{height:1%}
.tumblrAutoPager_page_info,
.tumblrAutoPager_page_separator {display:none;}
 
{block:ifLinkStyle1}
.nav a {
overflow:hidden;
padding:3px;
padding-top:4px;
margin-left:-1px;
margin-top:2px;
display:block;
font-family:'Viga', arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-align: left;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-decoration:none;
color: #000;
background-color:#EEEBEB;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;}
 
.nav a:hover{
border-radius:0px;
background-color:#cdcdcd;
border-right:62px solid black;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
text-decoration:none;}{/block:ifLinkStyle1}
 
{block:ifLinkStyle2}
.nav a{
font-size:9px;
font-family:courier new;
line-height:16px;
padding:2px;
letter-spacing:2px;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding-left:4px;
color:white;
background-color:{color:Sidebar Link Background};}
.nav a:hover{
background-color:{color:link hover};} {/block:ifLinkStyle2}
{CustomCSS}
</style>
 
<!-- INFINTE SCROLL SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ek9ly4s/M6Zmozr72/infintescroll3-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/j1tjexd/WYwm8ed44/like_script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
var $content = $('#content');
$content.masonry({itemSelector: '.entry', columnWidth:0
});
$content.infinitescroll({
navSelector : 'div#pagination',
nextSelector : 'div#pagination a#nextPage',
itemSelector : '.entry',
loading: {/*Loading...*/
finishedMsg: '',
img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/pX1lrx8xv/ajax-loader.gif'
},
bufferPx :600,
debug : false,
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function( newElements ) {
window.n = window.n || 0;
Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_page(++window.n);
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$newElems.hide();
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$content.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true, function(){$newElems.fadeIn(1500);} );
});
});
});
</script>
 
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Pagination}
<div id="pagination">
{block:NextPage}
<a id="nextPage" href="{NextPage}"></a>
{/block:NextPage}
{block:PreviousPage}
<a href="{PreviousPage}"></a>
{/block:PreviousPage}
</div>
{/block:Pagination}
{/block:IndexPage}
</head><body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scmplayer.net/script.js" 
data-config="{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':6,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':false,'repeat':1,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'Little Monster','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ere2Mstl8ww'},{'title':'All I Do','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSmqdzVY0s'},{'title':'Souls','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuxk8vW01pY'},{'title':'Elements','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf6LD2B_kDQ'},{'title':'High For This','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXGoo0HEma8'},{'title':'Cry Me A River','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0xHlPDn-mM'},{'title':'Lights','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqLGuRX_nLM'},{'title':'Only Flaw','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgbRDL6uRcA'},{'title':'B*tch Don%27t Kill My Vibe','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksmNpl4G3i4'},{'title':'Bullet Train','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QKARCPO3sA'},{'title':'Cherie Amour','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0a9SIG4DRbk'},{'title':'Swim Good','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcLsd8RCVq4'},{'title':'Stay','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uJjUz3T3jc'},{'title':'Radioactive','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6-S6IagSQU'},{'title':'Island In The Sun','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy4Y20dOlKs'},{'title':'Hold On','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x6DmYxnBaI'},{'title':'Titanium','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA_CNajQpJY'},{'title':'Payphone','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdHsJlQ5gaE'},{'title':'Lie To Me','url':'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTN8PS8jaIg'}]}" ></script>
<!-- SCM Music Player script end -->

 
<div id="content" class="infinite-scroll">
<div class="sidebar">
<center>
 
{block:ifshowblogtitle}<div class="blogtitle">
<a href="/">{title}</a>
</div>{/block:ifshowblogtitle}
 
{block:ifsidebarimage}<center><a href="/"><img src="{image:sidebar}" style="width:80%;" class="img"></a></center>{/block:ifsidebarimage}
 

 
<div style="margin-top:14px;"></div>
<span class="nav">
<a href="/">Home</a>
{block:AskEnabled}<a href="/ask">{text:ask title}</a>{/block:AskEnabled}
{block:ifLinkOneTitle}
<a href="{text:Link One}">{text:Link One Title}</a>{/block:ifLinkOneTitle}
{block:ifLinkTwoTitle}
<a href="{text:Link Two}">{text:Link Two Title}</a>{/block:ifLinkTwoTitle}
{block:ifLinkThreeTitle}
<a href="{text:Link Three}">{text:Link Three Title}</a>{/block:ifLinkThreeTitle}
{block:ifLinkFourTitle}
<a href="{text:Link Four}">{text:Link Four Title}</a>{/block:ifLinkFourTitle}
{block:ifLinkFiveTitle}
<a href="{text:Link Five}">{text:Link Five Title}</a>{/block:ifLinkFiveTitle}
{block:ifLinkSixTitle}
<a href="{text:Link Six}">{text:Link Six Title}</a>{/block:ifLinkSixTitle}
{block:ifLinkSevenTitle}
<a href="{text:Link Seven}">{text:Link Seven Title}</a>{/block:ifLinkSevenTitle}
{block:ifLinkEightTitle}
<a href="{text:Link Eight}">{text:Link Eight Title}{/block:ifLinkEightTitle}
{block:HasPages}{block:Pages}<a href="{URL}">{Label}</a>{/block:Pages} {/block:HasPages}
<a href="/archive">Archive</a>
<!-- DO NOT REMOVE CREDITS KEEP MY THEMES FREE -->
<a href="http://final-stand.tumblr.com" target="blank">Theme</a></center>
</span>
    
<div class="description">{description}</div>
    
</div>
 
{block:Posts}
<div id="content" class="infinite-scroll">
<div class="entry">
 
{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="photo">{LinkOpenTag}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/> </a>{LinkCloseTag}</div>
 
{block:ifshowphotopermalinks}
<div class="permalinks">
<ul class="buttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size="16"}</li>
<div class="noteslabel"><a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a></div>
<div class="noteslabel"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount}</a></div>
</ul>
</div>{/block:ifshowphotopermalinks}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}<div class="photobig"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="500px"/></div>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photo}
 
 
{block:Photoset}
<center>
<div class="photoset">
{block:IndexPage}{Photoset-250}{block:ifshowphotopermalinks}
<div class="permalinks">
<ul class="buttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size="16"}</li>
<div class="noteslabel"><a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a></div>
<div class="noteslabel"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount}</a></div>
</ul>
</div>{/block:ifshowphotopermalinks}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}
</center>
{/block:Photoset}
 
{block:Text}
<div class="text"><div style="padding:10px;">
<span class="title">{Title}</span>
{Body}
{block:IndexPage}
<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="supreme">{NoteCountwithLabel}</div></a></div></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Text}
 
{block:Link}
<div class="text"><div style="padding:10px;">
<center><a href="{URL}"><span class="title">{Name}</span></a></center>
<div style="margin-left:3px;">{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}</div>
{block:IndexPage}
<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="supreme">{NoteCountwithLabel}</div></a></div></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:Link}
 
{block:Quote}
<div class="text"><div style="padding:10px;">
<div style="margin-left:3px;">
{Quote}</span>
{block:Source}<strong>{Source}</strong>{/block:Source}
</div>
{block:IndexPage}
<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="supreme">{NoteCountwithLabel}</div></a></div></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Quote}
 
{block:Chat}
<div class="text"><div style="padding:10px;">
<div style="margin-left:3px;">
{block:Title}<span class="title">{title}</span>{/block:Title}
<ul class="chat">
{block:Lines}
<li class="user_{UserNumber}">
{block:Label}
<span class="label">{Label}</span>
{/block:Label}
{Line}
</li>
{/block:Lines}
</ul>
</div>
{block:IndexPage}
<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="supreme">{NoteCountwithLabel}</div></a></div></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Chat}
 
{block:Audio}
<div class="audio_text">
{block:AlbumArt} <a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{AlbumArtURL}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" style="{block:indexpage}width:250px;height:250px;{/block:indexpage}{block:permalinkpage}width:500px;height:500px;{/block:permalinkpage}"/>
{/block:AlbumArt}
<div style="margin-top:-4px;background-color:black;height:30px;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:5px;border-bottom:3px solid {color:center};
{block:indexpage}width:250px;{/block:indexpage}">
{AudioPlayerBlack}</div></center>
{/block:Audio}
 
{block:Answer}
<div class="text"><div style="padding:10px;">
<b>Q</b>: {Question}
<br><br>
{Answer}<br><i>asked by {Asker}</i></p>
{block:IndexPage}
<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="supreme">{NoteCountwithLabel}</div></a>
{/block:IndexPage}</div></div>{/block:Answer}
 
{block:Video}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="photoset">
<center>
{Video-250}</center>
<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="supreme">{NoteCountwithLabel}</div></a>
</div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
<center>
{Video-500}</center>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:Video}
 
{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:HasTags} &middot; {block:Tags}<a href="TagURL"> #{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:hasTags}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
 
{block:PostNotes}
<div class="notess">{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}
<br>{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
</div>
</div>
{/block:Posts}
 
{block:Pagination}
<div id="pagination">
{block:NextPage}
<a id="nextPage" href="{NextPage}"></a>
{/block:NextPage}
{block:PreviousPage}
<a href="{PreviousPage}"></a>
{/block:PreviousPage}
</div>
{/block:Pagination}
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>
 
<script>
window.onload = function () {
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<iframe id="my-like-frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>' );
document.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
var myLikeLink = event.target;
if( myLikeLink.className.indexOf( 'my-like' ) > -1 ) {
var myLikeFrame = document.getElementById( 'my-like-frame' ),
liked = ( myLikeLink.className == 'my-liked' ),
command = liked ? 'unlike' : 'like',
reblog = myLikeLink.getAttribute( 'data-reblog' ),
postId = myLikeLink.getAttribute( 'data-id' ),
oauth = reblog.slice( -8 ),
likeUrl = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + postId;
myLikeFrame.src = likeUrl;
liked ? myLikeLink.className = 'my-like'
: myLikeLink.className = 'my-liked';
};
}, false );
};
</script>
 
</body></html><!-- END OF THEME -->
```

I'd appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: target="_blank" is the right way and yes, it should go in the "a" tag, e.g. <a href="url" target="_blank">description</a>. However, whether or not the link will be opened in a new tab depends on the user's browser settings and how it handles "blank" links (new window or new tab). **Edit** have you cross checked whether the "_blank" setting actually makes it to the site? Check source code in browser to verify.

Comment: "Check source code in browser to verify"
Sorry, I'm new to this. Can you direct me on how to do this?